# Need String variable from class to equal the variable in another class, also ArrayList data to equal ArrayList data on another class

Tags: java, excel, arraylist

This class takes my excel file and then outputs all of the data into an `ArrayList`. I have another class in the package where, for sake of simplicity, I want the user to type either '1' or '2', where 1 and 2 are separate excel files. If the user types '1' I want the excel file to go through that initial program.  Then I want that `ArrayList`, with all the data it holds to shoot into another class where I have 64 sub arrays that will break up that data and then etc.

I've been working on this for days!  I'm trying to get out of being a beginner and into knowing what I'm doing.  I've worked pretty hard to make this question as specific as possible.  My methodology is probably not the most efficient to accomplish my goal. Better methods are appreciated.

//skip the overview unless you don't understand what I'm doing
Overview: The user types in a number, which selects the file to be processed into an array. Then the array goes to another class where it is separated into tons of smaller arrays. Then all of the numbers in each little array goes to a variable and each variable, then the user does another input which indicates a specific variable to be taken out of each little array, or two variables/2, or 3 variables/3, etc. Then, finally, those variables selected go through the main program which is all set up and dandy, then I will have an interface to display what each of those variables indicate it to display.

Main goal: User indicates which file to choose by pressing 1 or 2, file goes through program, program puts excel data into ArrayList, ArrayList containing that data shows up in a new class.

```
public class InputExcelFileOutputDataArrays {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = scan.nextInt();

/*Depending on what the user presses the variable excel will be
* equal to the String value of the file
*/
        if(input == 1){

        String excel = "C:/File";

    }

    if(input == 2){

    String excel = "C:/File2";
    }


}

}




public class ReadExcel2 {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    //here is where the String from the other class will equal this variable
    // excel and then all run nicely together
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("excel"));

    //create workbook instance that refers to .xlsx file
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

    //create a sheet object to retrieve the sheet
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    //this is for evaluate the cell type
    FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

    //The spreadsheet is transfered into this ArrayList
    ArrayList<Double> arrays = new ArrayList<Double>();


    //This here says ok everytime I see a number 
    //i'm going to put it in your ArrayList, and ignore strings
    for(Row row : sheet){

        for(Cell cell : row){

            switch(formulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(cell).getCellType())
            {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                arrays.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());

                break;

            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:

                break;
            }
        }

 }

public class TourneyArrays {

public static void main(String[] args){

//somehow make this equal to the data 
//from other ReadExcel class

public List<Double> arrays = new ArrayList<Double>();

//then I'm breaking it into subLists    
List<Double> numbers = arrays.subList(0, 33); //1
for(int i = 0; i<numbers.size(); i++ ){
    System.out.println(numbers.get(i));}
```

Comment: Like all beginners, you need to learn the two most fundamental things about how to be a successful programmer: decomposition and cleanliness.  You solve big problems by breaking them up into smaller ones.  You work hard to keep your code readable and not repeating yourself.    The way to fall into a hole is to write a wall of code without tests.  Write small methods, test them (using Junit) and build up your solution by calling small, working functions.  (PS - Your writing style needs work, too.)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't being specific enough, but the code for the "ReadExcel2" class runs fine. The problem arises as I'm trying to merge a class for an input to run the "ReadExcel2" class and also a class to hold the output of the ArrayList that the "ReadExcel2" class created with the excel file. I will have to use this project to learn how to incorporate the tests for future reference. As far as my writing style goes; I was not writing formally, my apologies.

Comment: You weren't clear at all.  I can't read your prose or your code.

Comment: There are three classes. The first class will determine the excel file that the second class will read, and input all the data into and ArrayList. The third class will be where the data inputted into that ArrayList will be held. I have two problems. Problem one is allowing that input in the first class run the excel file specified. Problem two is allowing that ArrayList data to be stored in a separate class.

Comment: Sorry, I've got nothing for you.  None of this makes sense.

Comment: I have multiple excel files with data. I have the program all set up that reads an excel file and stores all the data into an ArrayList. I am trying to write a program that asks "Hey, which file are you trying to use". Then it will run that file, creating the ArrayList. Then I need that ArrayList to go into a different class within this package. You no longer have to help me, but does this really not make any sense at all?

Comment: Update, I now realize how stupid I sounded lol got everything up and running though